# Using \href in a footnote to link to a specific page of a local PDF file yields "illegal parameter number"

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

I want to use a `\href` to link to a specific page in a local PDF file. This works fine, as long as I don't put that `\href` in a `\footnote`. Linking to just the PDF file without linking to a specific page also works fine, even in the footnote.

---

However, once I try to combine the two, or even add a `#` to the end of the PDF-link, I get the following error message:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.<to be read again>p ...18/Theo/Skript.pdf#page=123}{Herleitung}}
```

The full line that yields the error looks like this

```
\footnote{\href{run:C:/Users/Lars/Desktop/Uni/SoSe 18/Theo/Skript.pdf#page=123}{Herleitung}}.
```

and is within text environment. As far as I understand, `\footnote` somehow breaks once you use a `#` somewhere within its arguments, although I'm not sure why.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone has a solution to linking to a specific page in a PDF file within a footnote.

---

For reference, my desired output looks like this:

This is some text<sup>1</sup>.

This is more text.

This is the bottom of the page.

===========

<sup>1</sup> Herleitung(this word is the link to the pdf file)

Answer (score 1):

`\href` has to change category codes. But this does not work inside the argument of other commands (here: `\footnote`).

Fix: Instead of `#`, macro `\#` can be used:

```
\footnote{\href{http:www.example.org/foobar.pdf#page=123}{Herleitung}}
```

A simple GoToR link should be used for local PDF files. The page is specified by the optional argument, e.g.:

```
\href[page=2]{foobar.pdf}{Herleitung}
```

Comment: This runs, but breaks the link. I also tried using `{\#}` instead of `\#`, but the problem persists.

Comment: The new suggestion of adding the optional argument now (naturally) restores the link, but the `[page=123]` has no effect, meaning simply the first page of the pdf is linked.

Comment: @L.Kue Try a different PDF viewer.